# Weird URL issue (DNS fail for specific user)

Tags: domain-name-system, url

I run our research group's website, though I don't have direct access to the DNS records. Currently, our DNS set has an A record and a CNAME record as shown below

```
lima.wustl.edu.     28800   IN  CNAME   pappulab.wustl.edu.
pappulab.wustl.edu. 25083   IN  A   128.252.19.134
```

For one user using OSX, accessing `pappulab.wustl.edu` via Firefox (specifically) fails. However, accessing via Safari works, and if they access `lima.wustl.edu` using either Firefox or Safari they get the website.

I can connect to both through Safari, Firefox and Epiphany on Ubuntu. We're in the same (general) geographical area. This only started happening yesterday - i.e. prior to this they could access the website via both URLs.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this? Also, if you get an error when accessing [pappulab.wustl.edu](http://pappulab.wustl.edu) it would be great to know!

Comment: Sounds like a DNS cache issue on the user's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like EEAA said, sounds like DNS cache. Firefox maintains its own DNS cache in addition to OSX's DNS cache.

I would recommend the user restarts firefox and flushes OSX's cache (`sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`) and tries again.

So many caches in DNS, it's a common cause of issues especially "works on my box but not this one" types.

Comment: That's exactly what it was...